# How to check other column value

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

I am trying to do something very general case that is:

I am maintaining my project tasks in Excel, my Excel contains,

```
No, TASK, START-DATE, END-DATE, DUE-Days, STATUS
```

example:

```
1, task1, 01/05/2019, 4/05/2019, -5, Completed

Due-days(-5) =D1-TODAY
```

By using conditional format, if due-days is less than 0 then I am making that Due-days cell(D1) background color as Red. Till here I did and working fine.

But what I have to do is, even it's due-days are less than zero, if the task status(F1) is completed. I have to make the background color of D1 as Green.

I need to add one more condition to that conditional format, but I am not able to find any such option. How can I do this in Google Sheets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

green color:

```
=IF(AND($E1<0,$E1<>"",$F1="Completed"), 1)
```

red color:

```
=IF(AND($E1<0,$E1<>""), 1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Fewer characters than in the existing answer are need to achieve the result with, for instance IF functions rarely required for *Conditional* Formatting.

Please select ColumnsA:F and: Format > Conditional formatting..., Format cells if... Custom formula is and:

```
=sign($E1)*(left($F1)="C")
```

with green highlighting and repeat with instead:

```
=($E1<0)*($E1<>"")
```

and red highlighting.

Be sure to end up with the green rule above the red one in the list of rules.